# how to add function of copy in copy button in java swing

Tags: java, swing, copy

I am doing the code for copy from one location to another using java swing . I did here for `Browse`. but i don't know how to add function for copy button. please help me with the code. Thanks in advance. here is my full code. (sorry if i am wrong , i am using this for the first time)

```
/*
 For Browse button. 
 */
package com.design;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Browse extends JFrame implements 

ActionListener {

JButton button1, button2 ;
JTextField field1, field2;

public Browse () {
this.setLayout(null);

button1 = new JButton("Browse");
field1 = new JTextField();

field1.setBounds(30, 50, 200, 25);
button1.setBounds(240, 50, 100, 25);
this.add(field1);
this.add(button1);

button2 = new JButton("Copy");
button2.setBounds(150, 150, 100, 25);
this.add(button2);

button1.addActionListener(this);
setDefaultCloseOperation

(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE

);



}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
Chooser frame = new Chooser();
field1.setText(frame.fileName);

}

public static void main(String args[]) {

Browse frame = new Browse ();
frame.setSize(400, 300);
frame.setLocation(200, 100);
frame.setVisible(true);


}
}

class Chooser extends JFrame {

JFileChooser chooser;
String fileName;

public Chooser() {
chooser = new JFileChooser();
int r = chooser.showOpenDialog(new JFrame());
if (r == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
fileName = chooser.getSelectedFile().getPath();
System.out.println(fileName);
}
}
}
```

Comment: You are stating that you need the "copy function", but what is that? Copy what? Please explain the details of your problem and also tell why your current code isn't working for you.

Comment: And is your code always fully left justified? Isn't it hard for you to read and understand your code when it is formatted this way? It certainly is hard on us. Please fix your bad code formatting soon.

Comment: The `Chooser` doesn't sound good, with all the `JFrame`s.

Comment: After MouseEvent's comment, it would be better to use `JFileChoosers` build in open/save dialog's

Comment: Google [Java 7 file copy](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=java+7+file+copy&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&hl=en-gb&client=safari)

Answer (score 1):

This is the snippet to copy a file with Java 7

```
try {
    Files.copy(new File(your_source_file).toPath(), new File(your_target_file).toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

However, i'm not sure it is supported also with java 6 and previous versions, so this is a "diy" snippet that should work with all Java versions, it returns `true` if the file has been copied, `false` if some Exception is thrown:

```
public boolean copyfile(String sourceFile, String targetFile) {
   try {
      File f1 = new File(sourceFile);
      File f2 = new File(targetFile);
      InputStream in = new FileInputStream(f1);

      //Write to the new file
      OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(f2);

      byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
      int len;
      while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
         out.write(buf, 0, len);
      }
      in.close();
      out.close();
      System.out.println("File copied.");
   } catch (Exception ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
      return false;
   }
   return true;
}
```

Hope this helps